# How to calculate poisson distribution using R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, poisson

Given that the average number of people that complete a math problem is one every 5 minutes, what is the probability that the amount of time it takes between two people to do complete this math problem is more than 7 minutes?

I have no clue how to calculate this using R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the question I just realized was done with exponential distribution

Answer (score 0):

You can start by sampling the distribution of the sum of two independent, exponentially distributed random variables, each with rate parameter 1/5:

```r
n <- 1e06
lambda <- 1/5
x1 <- rexp(n, lambda)
x2 <- rexp(n, lambda)
y <- x1 + x2
```

If you don't know what `rexp()` is doing, then try `?rexp`. Can you take it from here?